# Realm data access

Tags: swift, realm

I have a ScoresModel using Swift for iOS which, when queried, produces the following result:

```
[0] ScoresModel {

    courseName = One;
    scoreOne = 4;
    scoreTwo = 10;
    scoreThree = 4;
    datePlayed = Jan 21, 2016;

},

[1] ScoresModel {

    courseName = Two;
    scoreOne = 5;
    scoreTwo = 9;
    scoreThree = 6;
    datePlayed = Feb 2, 2016;

}
```

My question being - When I receive the queried data how can I work with the individual tags received? i.e. all 'scoreOne' together, all 'scoreTwo' together, etc. I want to give feedback on all the data but not in it's raw form, for example average, best, worst, etc.
I hope the explanation is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For average of scoreOne you can write

```
realm.objects(ScoresModel).average("scoreOne")
```

for best

```
realm.objects(ScoresModel).max("scoreOne")
```

for worst

```
realm.objects(ScoresModel).min("scoreOne")
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that this implies interrogating the Model for everything you want? I would like to work with the data after one query when I retrieve the model. Is this at all possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by working with data after one query. You can use these methods anywhere you want. They will return average of all the `scoreOne`s in all of the `ScoreModel`s.

Comment: When trying your suggestion: let average = realm.objects(ScoresModel).average("scoreOne") I get an error 'Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred.

Comment: Try this `let average: Double? = realm.objects(ScoresModel).average("scoreOne")`